# Grabbing data from function

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function get_news($id) {
    $query      = mysql_query("SELECT `author`, `title`, `message` FROM `news` WHERE `id` = $id");
    $row        = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $title      = $row['title'];
    $author_id  = $row['author'];
    $message    = $row['message'];
}
```

and on my page I have this:

```
get_news($_GET['id']);
echo $title . '<br />' . $message;
```

However, the echo is not working at all. How can I grab the data from the function to make it work in the echo?

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on how to use functions, you are missing some pretty basic things.

Comment: I think you have a scope problem - $title (etc.) is only available inside your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return `$row`. It contains all the data.

```
function get_news($id) {
    $query      = mysql_query("SELECT `author`, `title`, `message` FROM `news` WHERE `id` = $id");
    $row        = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return $row;
}
```

And

```
$res = get_news($_GET['id']);
echo $res['title'] . '<br />' . $res['message'];
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Returning the array was enough.

```
function get_news($id) 
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `author`, `title`, `message` 
                      FROM `news` 
                      WHERE `id` = $id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

return $row;
}
```

In your page :

```
<? php
      print"<pre>";
      print_r(get_news($id));
     print"</pre>";
?>
```